# Image not visible in device but visible in layout Android

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I want to add a few images in my android application.

Here is the XML code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_launcher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context="com.example.rishabhgambhir.findthelost.Launcher">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo21"
    android:id="@+id/mainlogo"
    android:contentDescription="main logo"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="113dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/transparent_text_effect"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

What is possibly wrong in here?

Comment: yes post full code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add one line to image view xml.

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/mainlogo"
        android:contentDescription="main logo"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="113dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```